# Angular-ui modal: How to use the same controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Normally, I created a controller which used `$scope` syntax, so, I could pass a current $scope to a isolated scope of the modal directive as following:

```
$scope.openEditModal = function() {
    $scope.modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'views/budgets/mainbudgets/edit',
        scope: $scope // Passing a $scope variable
    });

    $scope.modalInstance.close();
};
```

However, I just switched the controller to use `this` syntax:

```
var self = this;
// User edit modal
this.openEditModal = function() {
    self.modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'views/budgets/mainbudgets/edit',
        scope: self; // This doesn't work
    });

    self.modalInstance.close();
};
```

So, how can I pass a current `this` to be used in isolated scope of the modal directive?

**EDIT**

Here is the whole code of my controller:

```
angular.module('sms.budgets').controller('BudgetsMainController', ['$scope', 'Global', '$modal', '$timeout', '$rootScope','Budgets', function($scope, Global, $modal, $timeout, $rootScope,Budgets) {
    var self = this;
    this.newBudget = {};
    this.budgets = [];

    function init() {
        var data = {};

        // Load main budget from DB
        Budgets.load('main-budgets').success(function(budgets) {
            self.budgets = budgets || [];
        });
    }
    init();

    /**
     * Create a new main budget
     */
    this.create = function() {
        var data = {};
        data.budget = self.newBudget;
        data.dbName = 'Budget';
        Budgets.create('budgets', data).success(function() {
            self.isSuccess = true;
            $timeout(function() {
                self.isSuccess = false;
            }, 5000);
        }).error(function(err) {
            self.isError = true;
            $timeout(function() {
                self.isError = false;
            }, 5000);
        });
    };

    this.edit = function() {
        self.modalInstance.close();
    };

    // User edit modal
    this.openEditModal = function() {
        var newScope = $rootScope.$new();
        newScope.modalInstance = self.modalInstance;
        newScope.edit = self.edit;
        self.modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'views/budgets/mainbudgets/edit',
            scope: newScope

        });

        self.modalInstance.close();
    };

    this.cancelEditModal = function() {
        self.modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };

}]);
```

Comment: @pixelbits I'm using angular-ui, modal directive.

Comment: self isn't a scope. Shouldn't you pass a scope to the scope property?

Comment: I'm using `controller as` syntax that why I don't have a $scope injected to my controller. I know that `self` isnt a scope but I don't know how to make the modal directive work in this situation.

Comment: Scope should be injected in the controller.  Can you show your controller code?

Comment: Why are you creating a new scope and passing into your modal? Why don't you just pass the $scope that's injected into your controller?

Comment: If I pass a $scope, I will get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'dismiss' of undefined` because I didn't bind any data to $scope, actually, I forgot to remove it from my controller as I used `controller as` syntax I don't need it anymore. Since I knew that I can't pass `scope: this` to the directive. I tried in different way which is to create a new scope and try to bind the data, however, it doesn't work.

Comment: @LVarayut Your last approach, what do you mean by it does n't work? what error do you see?

Comment: @pixelbits Thanks for your help. It was my stupid mistake. Your approach totally works fine.

Comment: @PSL Thanks for asking. It worked right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use this as a scope. They are different. Since $scope is a internal variable of AngularJS you have to keep it as it.

To show that, I've created a Plunkr (open the console and see the diffence between this and $scope)

http://plnkr.co/edit/DkWQk4?p=preview

Anyway, is a good practise to use a different scope on the modal controller. Here you have an example showing how to communicate between the main controller and the modal controller:

From the **MainCtrl**:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'views/parts/modalUrlImg.html',
  controller: 'ModalUrlCtrl',
  resolve: {
    url: function () { // pass the url to the modal controller
      return $scope.imageUrl;
    }
  }
});

// when the modal is closed, get the url param
modalInstance.result.then(function (url) { 
    $scope.courses[i].imageUrl = url;
});
```

From the **Modal Ctrl**:

```
.controller('ModalUrlCtrl', function($scope, $modalInstance, url) {

  $scope.url = url; // get the url from the params

  $scope.Save = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.url);
  };

  $scope.Cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };

  $scope.Clean = function () {
    $scope.url = '';
  };
});
```

Hope this help you, cheers.

**--- EDIT ---**

You can keep the controller as syntax. In fact, you must mix both syntax, since you can only use this to add vars and functions, but not tu access other scope things, such as $scope.$on...

So, to do that in your case, just pass $scope:

```
var self = this;
// User edit modal
this.openEditModal = function() {
    self.modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'views/budgets/mainbudgets/edit',
        scope: $scope;
    });

    self.modalInstance.close();
};
```

I've tried in the updated plunkr and it's working now:

http://plnkr.co/edit/DkWQk4?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your response. I knew the different between `this` and `$scope`. So, I chose to use `this`, `controller as`, syntax. Is there anyway I can use the same controller in modal directive? Please see my edited question for the whole code of my controller.

Comment: See the edited answer and the plunker that shows it working now

Comment: I'm sorry, the link in the answer was wrong, the correct link is http://plnkr.co/edit/DkWQk4?p=preview . I've updated the link anyway

Answer (score 0):

> $scope != controller

By passing `this` to `$modal.open()` you are passing the reference of the controller and not the scope. Try passing `$scope` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I knew the `$scope != controller`. However, I don't know how to use the same controller in modal directive if I'm using `controller as` syntax.